# how to disable SQL_SAFE_UPDATES in google cloud

Tags: select, sql-update, updates

I am using Google Cloud SQL and when running the following query:

```
SELECT Counter 
  FROM Ms_Counter 
 WHERE Counter_Id= 'Cust'
   AND Cpy_Id= 'A001'
   AND Counter_Year=2019 
   FOR UPDATE; 

UPDATE Ms_Counter 
   SET Counter= Counter+1,
       Usrup='Me',
       Dtup='2019-03-24' 
 WHERE Counter_Id= 'Cust'
   AND Cpy_Id= 'A001'
   AND Counter_Year=2019;
```

Error trace

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe
>   mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

**Update 1**

Safe-update is turned off by default on Cloud SQL

Comment: Could any one inform me how to disable safe update in google cloud?

Comment: the above code return an error if safe update is not turn off.

Comment: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.